# Unable to use 'ion-stepper' in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to use ion-stepper in my ionic4 app but it is giving me this exception, First I was getting 'ionic-angular' error so since I am using ionic4 so i had to change it to @ionic/angular error but I have no idea how to solve this because its saying ngIf is not defined but I have not used any ngIf condition in my html.

```
Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("                         [active]="i <= selectedIndex">
          </ion-step-header>
          <div [ERROR ->]*ngIf="!isLast" class="ionic-stepper-horizontal-line"></div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
"): ng:///IonicStepperModule/IonicStepperComponent.html@11:15
Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
                             [active]="i <= selectedIndex">
          </ion-step-header>
          [ERROR ->]<div *ngIf="!isLast" class="ionic-stepper-horizontal-line"></div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
"): ng:///IonicStepperModule/IonicStepperComponent.html@11:10
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.
1. If 'ngForOf' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("ontal-container">
     <div class="ionic-stepper-horizontal-header-container">
       <ng-container [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let step of _steps; let i = index; let isLast = last">
          <ion-step-header [index]="i""): ng:///IonicStepperModule/IonicStepperComponent.html@3:21
Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("-stepper-horizontal-container">
     <div class="ionic-stepper-horizontal-header-container">
       [ERROR ->]<ng-container *ngFor="let step of _steps; let i = index; let isLast = last">
          <ion-step-head"): ng:///IonicStepperModule/IonicStepperComponent.html@3:7
Can't bind to 'ngTemplateOutlet' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.
1. If 'ngTemplateOutlet' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<div class="ionic-vertical-content" *ngIf="i === selectedIndex">
                     <ng-container [ERROR ->][ngTemplateOutlet]="step.content"></ng-container>
                 </div>
            </div>
"): ng:///IonicStepperModule/IonicStepperComponent.html@20:35
Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("talStepTransition]="getAnimationDirection(i)">
                 <div class="ionic-vertical-content" [ERROR ->]*ngIf="i === selectedIndex">
                     <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="step.content"></n"): ng:///IonicStepperModule/IonicStepperComponent.html@19:53
Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("-content"
                 [@horizontalStepTransition]="getAnimationDirection(i)">
                 [ERROR ->]<div class="ionic-vertical-content" *ngIf="i === selectedIndex">
                     <ng-container ["): ng:///IonicStepperModule/IonicStepperComponent.html@19:17
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.
1. If 'ngForOf' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
      </ng-container>
    </div>
    <ng-container [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let step of _steps; let i = index; let isLast = last">
        <div class="ionic-stepper-hori"): ng:///IonicStepperModule/IonicStepperComponent.html@14:18
Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
      </ng-container>
    </div>
    [ERROR ->]<ng-container *ngFor="let step of _steps; let i = index; let isLast = last">
        <div class="ioni"): ng:///IonicStepperModule/IonicStepperComponent.html@14:4
Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
<div [ERROR ->]*ngIf="mode === 'horizontal'" class="ionic-stepper-horizontal-container">
     <div class="ionic-step"): ng:///IonicStepperModule/IonicStepperComponent.html@1:5
Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
[ERROR ->]<div *ngIf="mode === 'horizontal'" class="ionic-stepper-horizontal-container">
     <div class="ionic"): ng:///IonicStepperModule/IonicStepperComponent.html@1:0
Can't bind to 'ngTemplateOutlet' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.
1. If 'ngTemplateOutlet' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("ction(i)">
                 <div class="ionic-vertical-content">
                     <ng-container [ERROR ->][ngTemplateOutlet]="step.content"></ng-container>
                 </div>
            </div>
"): ng:///IonicStepperModule/IonicStepperComponent.html@42:35
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.
1. If 'ngForOf' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

<div *ngIf="mode === 'vertical'" class="ionic-stepper-vertical-container">
    <ng-container [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let step of _steps; let i = index; let isLast = last">
        <ion-step-header [index]="i"
 "): ng:///IonicStepperModule/IonicStepperComponent.html@28:18
Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("

<div *ngIf="mode === 'vertical'" class="ionic-stepper-vertical-container">
    [ERROR ->]<ng-container *ngFor="let step of _steps; let i = index; let isLast = last">
        <ion-step-header"): ng:///IonicStepperModule/IonicStepperComponent.html@28:4
Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
</div>

<div [ERROR ->]*ngIf="mode === 'vertical'" class="ionic-stepper-vertical-container">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let s"): ng:///IonicStepperModule/IonicStepperComponent.html@27:5
Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
</div>

[ERROR ->]<div *ngIf="mode === 'vertical'" class="ionic-stepper-vertical-container">
    <ng-container *ngFor=""): ng:///IonicStepperModule/IonicStepperComponent.html@27:0
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2430)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:20605)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:26171)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:26158)
    at compiler.js:26101
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:26101)
    at compiler.js:26011
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2421)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:26010)
```

Comment: delete your node_modules folderand run `npm install`

Comment: Please add your template code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use this:

- https://github.com/HsuanXyz/ionic-stepper

It seems like it probably doesn't support Ionic 4. There are [two unanswered issues](https://github.com/hsuanxyz/ionic-stepper/issues) about this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the ionic version that matters, its the later version of angular which using ivy render engine who blocks this library from import, so either contact the author of this library or you may try refactor it if you like.
otherwise you may consider the mat-stepper or premng or any other useful supports for load a stepper